# jQuery Option Select

Tags: jquery

How could I make the required input text boxes show when the correct drop down item is selected.

**Example:**

When yes is selected it will ask for the details about the domain.

```
<label for="domainRequired">Domain required: </label>
<select name="domainRequired">
    <option value="pleaseSelect">Please Select</option>
    <option value="yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="no">No</option>
</select>
```

**Update:**

**HTML:**

```
<label for="domainRequired">Domain required: </label>
            <select name="domainRequired">
                <option value="pleaseSelect">Please Select</option>
                <option value="yes">Yes</option>
                <option value="no">No</option>
            </select>
            <label for="domaintobereged">Domain:</label><input name="domaintobereged" id="domaintobereged" type="text" placeholder="http://"/>
```

**jQuery:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#domainRequired').change(function() {
            var $domain = $('#domaintobereged');
            if ($(this).val() == 'yes') {
                $domain.show();
            } else {
                $domain.hide();
            }
        });
     });
    </script>
```

I have loaded my jQuery in the footer above the `</body>` tag:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="http://#.co.nz/_assets/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

Comment: What are these input text boxes you speak of?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/3XYMT/

Comment: @zerkms move that to answer, i'll upvote it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing you have added the appropriate id's to your elements - the major work could be done as:

```
$('#domainRequired').change(function() {
    var $domain = $('#domain');
    if ($(this).val() == 'yes') {
        $domain.show();
    } else {
        $domain.hide();
    }
});​
```

or even

```
$('#domainRequired').change(function() {
    $('#domain').toggle($(this).val() == 'yes');
});​
```

Live examples: http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/3XYMT/ & http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/3XYMT/1

Comment: Thanks,  I have updated my question I cant get it to hide.  Is there a way to hide the specific label?

Comment: @Jess McKenzie: I don't understand what you mean

Comment: I can hide the #domaintobereged input using css but I can't get it to show or hide using my code.  When using display:none; or the jQuery the label still shows <label for="domaintobereged">Domain:</label>

Comment: @Jess McKenzie: could you please reproduce that on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: @Jess McKenzie: I wrapped both label and input in one div

Answer (score 0):

```
$('select[name="domainRequired"]').change(function(e){
    if(e.target.value === 'yes') {
        // Do stuff
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).

Used roughly like this:

```
$("[name=domainRequired]").change(function()
{
    // Show a text box if YES was selected (perhaps using .val() ?)

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Cross browser solution:

```
var $select = $('select[name="domainRequired"]');
$select.change(function() {
    if ($select.find('option:selected').val() == 'yes') {
        // make inputs required
    } else {
        // make inputs optional
    }
});
```